# Loop a function based on the value before?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to loop my formula: `pv = pv - p - (r * pv)`, 60 times to calculate the current debt after 5 years (60 months), to do that I need, for every new calculations, the value `pv` before to calculate the new value.

This is what I got so far, but I dont get the right final value...

```
def functionname(pv, rent, year):
    r = (rent / 100) / 12
    p = pv * (r * ((1 + r) ** (year*12))) / (((1 + r) * (year*12)) - 1)
    for i in range(0, 61):
        pv = pv - p - (r * pv)
    return pv


pv = int(input("Type your debt: "))
rent = float(input("Type yearly rent: "))
year = int(input("Type how many years you want to pay of the loan: "))

pv = functionname(pv, rent, year)
print("The current debt after 5 years is:",pv)
```

Comment: Can you provide an input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: What are your input values, expected right result and actual wrong result?

Comment: `range(0, 61)` definitely looks wrong. Do you get the correct result with `range(60)`?

Comment: You can also make your `pv` loop depend on `year` variable: `for i in range(year * 12)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop N times, just pass a single parameter N to range function. For example this loop will run 60 times. Your current for loop runs 61 times (from 0 to 60).

```
def functionname(pv, retn, year):
    r = (rent / 100) / 12
    p = pv * (r * ((1 + r) ** (year*12))) / (((1 + r) * (year*12)) - 1)
    for i in range(60):
        pv = pv - p - (r * pv)
    return pv


pv = int(input("Type your debt: "))
rent = float(input("Type yearly rent: "))
year = int(input("Type how many years you want to pay of the loan: "))

pv = functionname(pv, rent, year)
print("The current debt after 5 years is:",pv)
```

Comment: So if I type for example values:  "Type your debt: 50 000", "Type yearly rent: 5", "Type how many years...: 9". The final answer is: 7681.75. The right answer should be: 24534.03. 

No I dont get the correct answer with range(60).

The range need to be 0,61 because the start value is 0 and the stop value is 60-1, therefor 61, right?

Comment: @AdamTörnqvist Maybe first start with smaller input values until you get correct results you want, then try larger values.